# Show flash message if redirected to login form

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3

I'm using FOSUserBundle.

When a user try to reach a protected URL, it's redirected to the login form. This is OK, but I want to show a flash message informing the user why he has been redirected to the login form. Something like: 'You have reached a protected area. You must login into your account ....'

This message must be displayed only when the user is redirected from a protected area, not when the user goes to the login URL directly.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an event listener for the HttpKernel exception event, which happens to be the example given in the Cookbook [chapter on creating event listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html).

You can find the list of exceptions [here](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Exception.html). I'm guessing you'd want the `AccessDeniedHttpException`.